# wait for multiple charts load

Tags: python, selenium

I have multiple charts in one dashboard. I want to wait until all charts loaded. I have done this code in java. I want to done with python.
Please help

```
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

       public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {

           Iterator<WebElement> eleIterator = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@class='loading']")).iterator();

           while (eleIterator.hasNext())                    
             {
               boolean displayed = false;
               try
               {
                   displayed = eleIterator.next().isDisplayed();     
               }

               catch (NoSuchElementException | StaleElementReferenceException e) 
               {
                   displayed = false;
               }
               if (displayed) 
               {
                   return false;

               } 
             }
           }
           return true;
       }
   });
```

I want this code using python or any suggestion how to wait until all charts loaded in selenium python

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for all the elements to be visible or present in the DOM using the explicit wait in python.

```py
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//img[@class='loading']")))
```

OR

```py
WebDriverWait(driver,30)until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//img[@class='loading']")))
```

To use explicit wait you have to import the following

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: when xpath loading is disabled then all charts get loaded

Comment: You have to insert the locator for the charts in that case. Or you can directly wait for the attribute change. Can you provide the HTML of the element that has this class present in attribute?